# Application of xreg in forecasts

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, predictive-models, prediction

I'm trying to compare my forecast values with real values and assess the difference. I have 130 observations which are number of deaths (dependent variable). As well I have data for interaction variables like a pollution or temperature (exogenous variables). Data is recorder in monthly manner and I'm using auto.arima for all my models with arguments stepwise and approximation set to FALSE. My two questions are:

1. If I want check divergence between forecast and real values, while accounting for interaction variables should i go for:

a) forecasting the model with forecasted xreg values.

b) forecasting the model with real values in xreg.

I guess the first possibility is a typicall forecast while the second sounds more like outlier detection method to me. Am i right?

2. If I forecast the xreg, can I mix forecast techniques for different variables and the main model itself? Or it should be uniform? Like TBATS for variables and ARIMA for the main model.